# Problem using User Secrets in Application Console (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, git

I am new to this concept of using User secrets in .Net.

My purpose of using it is to hide my sensative data while pushing it to Git.

So I created a dummy application to test it out first before applying it on my real projects.

I followed this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@granthair5/how-to-add-and-use-user-secrets-to-a-net-core-console-app-a0f169a8713f).

First of all, I installed the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets using NuGet :

[image: extension]

In step Two they say right click on .csproj since **I dont have it listed in the explorer** so I went to the folder then clicked on :

[image]

Then I added the userId :

[image]

Then they ask me to do this :

[image]

Since My Nuguet package doesn't exists inside an Item group I added it in the bottom next to where Nuguet is mentioned :
[image]

Then in step 3 :
The first command worked but when I tried typing the second **it gaves me this error**  :

[image]

I don't know if I am going on the right path or no. That's why I am asking if those steps I am following are correcte I hope someone could please help me solve the problems I accountered. And if the process I am following is wrong I am open to any advice or direction to new tutorials or solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not aware of this at all but i am aware that you are editing wrong `.csproj` file. File above that one `calculator` is also `.csproj` but you cannot see that. Try editing that one.

Comment: Thank you very much I was ignoring this fact. I'll try editing that file and see what will happen. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately still having the same Error after using the correct file .csproj.I edited the post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running the `dotnet user-secrets set` command in the folder that contains your `Calculator.sln` solution instead of your `Calculator.csproj` project.

From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows#set-a-secret):

> Run the following command from the directory in which the project file exists:
>
> `dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"`